# "Didn't", "did not", "don't" and "do not" problem

Tags: word-usage

Though English is for us all, I think it's not for me.

I get confused every time I read books or hear people speak the words *didn't, did not, don't and do not.* I cannot figure out the right word to use: they all seem alike.

Would you please make me understand where the difference lies?

Comment: This is easy! There is no such thing as "didn\`t". Likewise, "don\`t" doesn't exist. The \` is the [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent). It's something you put atop of letters. A letter part, not a punctuation mark. You can't use it as an apostrophe. That's like replacing a b with a d. They might look very similar, but they don't mean remotely the same thing.

Comment: I've fixed the punctuation issue.